# Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2016 - Missing move by sender option

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I have been wanting to combat my busy inbox using Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2016 (through 365), and I have used rules on other platforms before but never on Microsoft. I had the assumption that there would be an easy, quick to access option to move all messages automatically by sender (say if I have a lot of messages that come in quickly by abc@domain.com, and I would like to move them all into a folder automatically, out of my inbox). I know that I could create a new rule but say I have 200+ senders that I would like to do this to (which I do), this repetitive process is tedious and I feel there exists a much easier way to do this.

On Microsoft's training website I found this. Under "Create a rule based on sender's name or a contact group", there should exist an option to "Move messages from ", but for me that option (and the next from recipient's name) do not exist, and all I see for me is "edit rules", and "apply...".

Does anyone else have this error or any intuition as to why this is happening for me? The inbox I am wanting to organize is a Gmail account, by the way

Comment: Did you select the correct folder (Inbox) when trying creating a rule? I notice that some folders only provide two or three options under the 'Rules' drop down, such as the Trash folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move email from several contacts to a single destination folder, you can use one rule for that. But, you'll need one rule for each destination folder, because you need to use different filter conditions to select which mail goes where.

I suspect it would be okay with 200 separate contact filters, but I've never tried adding more than 5-10 filter conditions to a rule, so you might reach an upper limit at some point — let us know!

You can filter the incoming email by sender and by the folder it's already in before applying the rule; in effect, this allows you choose where to move it from, although the mindset behind the feature is a bit different than that.

If you want to implement complex logic, such as, "Move mail from sender A to folder Y, but only if it's in folder Z already; but move all mail from sender B to folder Y," then I'd recommend making separate rules for that. (I don't think you can set up precedence rules in filter conditions.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! But I'm not quite sure you understood what I was asking- I know how to use and manipulate rules in Outlook (easy and complex) and use filters. What I don't know is if there is an easy way to just automatically send messages from a single sender to a single folder. In the tutorial I linked above it shows that there should be an option in the "rules" drop down, but I don't see it in my installed application- I have also confirmed that I have the same version as the tutorial.